# Logback for different log levels

Tags: slf4j, spring-logback

Used Slf4j. Need to a set scheme where `log.info()` send only to console, `log.debug()` console and file. I try to do with `logback.xml`, but all data write to file, how to write to file only debug level?

```
<configuration>
    <property name="HOME_LOG" value="logs/app.log"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.FileAppender">
        <file>${HOME_LOG}</file>
        <append>true</append>
        <immediateFlush>true</immediateFlush>
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="pro.tradeshare" level="debug" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
    </logger>
</configuration>
```